# Finitely generated groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups such that $G= \langle a,b\rangle$, $H=
\langle c,d\rangle$. If o(a) is not equal to either $o(c)$ or $o(d)$. Can $G$ and $H$ be isomorphic? Can someone explain how to think of examples for such cases? I usually deal with the standard examples of group theory but I think we need a wider range of examples for handling such problems.

Answer (score 4):

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_2 = \langle x, y \mid x^2 = y^2 = 1 \rangle$ be the free product of $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with itself, and let $H = \langle xy, y \rangle$.  Since $x = (xy) y^{-1}$, then $H = G$.  Then $o(x) = o(y) = 2$, but $o(xy) = \infty$.

Comment: One problem,If $f$ is an isomorphism between the groups given then should not $f$ map a generator of one group to the generator of the other,Is something wrong in my point?

Comment: @learnmore I don't understand the question.  The point is that $\{xy, y\}$ is a set of generators for $G$; there can be many different sets of generators for a given group.  The isomorphism in this example is just the identity map.  It really amounts to rewriting elements using the new generating set.

Comment: My point is suppose if $G$ is generated by $a,b$ and $H$ by $c,d$,in order to have an isomorphism between them should not we map $a\rightarrow c$ or $a $ to $d$.because generators should map to generators

Comment: @learnmore That is one possibility for a map, but not the only one.  For instance $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $1$, but the map $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\varphi(1) = 3$ is certainly an isomorphism.  The reason is that $3$ is a another generator for $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: thanks I have understood+1

Answer (score 2):

Another example: $\mathbb{Z}_{10}= \langle 3,7 \rangle$, $\mathbb{Z}_{10}= \langle 2, 5 \rangle$, $o(3)=o(7)=10$, $o(2)=5$ and $o(5)=2$.

Comment: good example +1

Answer (score 1):

For a finite example, in which $|a|,|b|,|c|$ and $|d|$ are all coprime, we could take $A_7 = \langle (1,2)(3,4),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) \rangle = \langle (1,2,3),(3,4,5,6,7) \rangle$.

Two randomly chosen permutations of $n$ points will generate $A_n$ or $S_n$ with high probability, so it is easy to find examples of this kind.

Comment: One problem,If $f$ is an isomorphism between the groups given then should not $f$ map a generator of one group to the generator of the other,Is something wrong in my point?

Comment: @learnmore yes, what you say correct, but so what?